# A variable in an enum will not reset to its original number

Tags: java, enums

So I am making this game, and whenever the "attack" button is clicked, the enemy and the player lose health. The player can heal but when he gets in another fight with a monster, the monster's health is still at 0 or 1 while the player's health is healed. I tried to make a method to fix it but it still doesn't work. Any solutions?

(Sorry if my code is sloppy. I assume the Panel or Label class is unnecessary.)

The main class:

```
    public static void mainScreen(JPanel p)
    {
        JButton points = new JButton("stats");
        points.setLayout(null);
        points.setBounds(smallButton);
        points.setLocation(510, 5);
        points.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
              {
                  p.removeAll();
                  pointsScreen(p);
                  p.repaint();
              }
            });
        JButton battle = new JButton("battle");
        battle.setLayout(null);
        battle.setBounds(smallButton);
        battle.setLocation(510, 30);
        battle.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
              {
                  Battle b = new Battle(strpoints, defpoints, luckpoints, health, currentHealth);
                  p.removeAll();
                  p.add(battle);
                  battleScreen(p,b);
                  p.repaint();
              }
            });
        p.add(battle);
        p.add(points);
    }

    public static void battleScreen(JPanel p, Battle b)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        Label enemy = new Label("You've encountered a "+b.e.getName()+"!",200,20, new Dimension(200,30), Color.YELLOW);
        p.add(enemy); // enemy encountered

        Label enemyHp = new Label("Health: "+b.e.getCurrentEnemyHp()+"/"+b.e.getEnemyHp(),500,100, new Dimension(100,25), Color.GREEN);
        p.add(enemyHp); // enemy's hp
        Label enemySt = new Label("Strength: "+b.e.getStr(),500,125, new Dimension(100,25), Color.ORANGE);
        p.add(enemySt); // enemy's str
        Label enemyDf = new Label("Defence: "+b.e.getDef(),500,150, new Dimension(100,25), Color.CYAN);
        p.add(enemyDf); // enemy's def
        Label enemyloot = new Label("Loot: "+(b.e.getLoot()+r.nextInt(luckpoints + 1)),500,175, new Dimension(100,25), Color.YELLOW);
        p.add(enemyloot); // enemy's loot

        Label hp = new Label("Health: "+currentHealth+"/"+health,0,100, new Dimension(100,25), Color.GREEN);
        p.add(hp); // player hp
        Label str = new Label("Strength: "+strpoints,0,125, new Dimension(100,25), Color.ORANGE);
        p.add(str); //player str
        Label def = new Label("Defence: "+defpoints,0,150, new Dimension(100,25), Color.CYAN);
        p.add(def); //player def

        Label activity = new Label("What's your next move?",0,340, new Dimension(620,35), Color.WHITE);

        p.add(activity); // battle activity feed

        Label enemyImg = new Label(null, 390, 100, new Dimension(100,100), null);
        enemyImg.setIcon(b.e.getImage());
        p.add(enemyImg); // picture of the enemy

        Label img = new Label(null, 110, 100, new Dimension(100,100), null);
        img.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src\\player.png"));
        p.add(img); // picture of the player


        JButton done = new JButton("done");
        done.setLayout(null);
        done.setBounds(smallButton);
        done.setLocation(420, 280);
        done.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
              {
                  p.removeAll();
                  p.repaint();
                  if(currentHealth <= 0)
                  {
                      if(activity.getText().contains("been"))
                      {
                        strpoints = 0;
                        defpoints = 0;
                        luckpoints = 0;
                        freepoints = 10;
                        gold = 100;
                        health = 10;
                        currentHealth = 10;
                      }

                        p.removeAll();
                        pointsScreen(p);
                        p.repaint();
                        p.add(activity);
                        p.remove(activity);
                  }
                  else
                      mainScreen(p);

              }
            });



        JButton attack = new JButton("attack");
        attack.setLayout(null);
        attack.setBounds(smallButton);
        attack.setLocation(100, 280);
        attack.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
              {
                  int dmg2player = b.e.getStr() + r.nextInt(2) - defpoints/2;
                  if(dmg2player < 1)
                      dmg2player = 1;
                  int dmg2enemy = strpoints + r.nextInt(2) - b.e.getDef()/2;
                  if(dmg2enemy < 1)
                      dmg2enemy = 1; // calculates damage dealt by you and enemy


                  b.e.updateEnemyHp(dmg2enemy);
                  currentHealth = currentHealth - dmg2player; 
                  hp.setText("Health: "+currentHealth+"/"+health);
                  enemyHp.setText("Health: "+b.e.getCurrentEnemyHp()+"/"+b.e.getEnemyHp()); //updates player and enemy's current hp


                  activity.setText("You dealt "+dmg2enemy+" damage to "+b.e.getName()+" and you received "+dmg2player+" damage!"); //updates battle log


                  if(currentHealth <= 0)
                  {
                      p.removeAll();
                      activity.setText("You have been defeated by a "+b.e.getName()+"!");
                      p.add(done);
                      p.add(activity);
                      p.repaint();
                      b.e.resetHp();
                  } // happens whenever the player is ded as fuk
                  else if(b.e.getCurrentEnemyHp() <= 0)
                  {
                      gold = gold + b.e.getLoot();
                      freepoints = freepoints + (b.e.getLoot()/10);
                      p.removeAll();
                      activity.setText("You have defeated the "+b.e.getName()+" and earned "+b.e.getLoot()+" gold along with "+(b.e.getLoot()/10)+" points!");
                      p.add(done);
                      p.add(activity);
                      p.repaint();



                  } // happens when the enemy is ded as fuk

                  else
                  {
                      p.remove(hp);
                        p.remove(enemyHp);
                        p.remove(activity);
                        p.add(hp);
                        p.add(enemyHp);
                        p.add(activity);
                        p.repaint();
                  } // happens when nobody is ded as fuk

              }
            });
        p.add(attack);

        JButton flee = new JButton("flee (" + (b.e.getLoot()/2)+"g)");
        flee.setLayout(null);
        flee.setBounds(new Rectangle(120,20));
        flee.setLocation(420, 280);
        flee.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
              {

                  if(gold > b.e.getLoot()/2)
                  {
                      gold = gold - (b.e.getLoot()/2);
                      p.removeAll();
                      mainScreen(p);
                  } else 
                  {
                      activity.setText("You need "+b.e.getLoot()/2+" gold to escape!");
                      p.remove(activity);
                      p.add(activity);
                  } 

                  p.repaint();


              }
            });
        p.add(flee);


    }
}
```

The battle class.

```
public class Battle
{
    int str;
    int def;
    static int luck;
    int hp;
    int currenthp;
    Enemy e;


    public Battle(int s, int d, int l,int hp, int chp)
    {
        this.hp = hp;
        Random r = new Random();

        currenthp = chp;
        str = s;
        def = d;
        luck = l;

        switch(r.nextInt(5))
        {
        case 0: e = Enemy.rat;
        return;
        case 1: e = Enemy.hunter;
        return;
        case 2: e = Enemy.wolf;
        return;
        case 3: e = Enemy.troll;
        return;
        case 4: e = Enemy.demon;
        return;
        }
    }

    enum Enemy
    {

        rat("Rat",2,2,10,10,new ImageIcon("src\\rat.png")),
        hunter("Hunter",4,4,20,25,new ImageIcon("src\\hunter.png")), 
        wolf("Wolf",5,3,15,40,new ImageIcon("src\\wolf.png")),
        troll("Troll",4,7,30,75,new ImageIcon("src\\troll.png")), 
        demon("Demon",6,6,25,100,new ImageIcon("src\\demon.png"));

        private String name;
        private int estr;
        private int edef;
        private int ehp;
        private int gold;
        private int ecHp;
        private ImageIcon img;

        Enemy(String n, int s, int d, int h, int g, ImageIcon i)
        {
            name = n;
            estr = s;
            edef = d;
            ehp = h;
            gold = g;
            ecHp = h;
            img = i;
        }

        public void updateEnemyHp(int dmg)
        {
            ecHp = ecHp - dmg;
        }

        public int getCurrentEnemyHp()
        {
            return ecHp;
        }

        public int getEnemyHp()
        {
            return ehp;
        }


    public int getStr()
    {
        return estr;
    }

    public int getDef()
    {
        return edef;
    }


public ImageIcon getImage()
{
    return img;
}

public int getLoot()
{
    return gold;
    }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }


    public void resetHp() {
        ecHp=ehp;

    }
    }

}
```

Comment: Posting this much code won't help you get answers. You should instead try to debug your code to at least find the portion of it that might be causing the problem.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by: The player can heal but when he gets in another fight with a monster, the monster's health is still at 0 or 1. You never said anything about the other monster??? Try and be more precise, and please remove the unneeded code, like the imports please, it will be easier to read it.